# Showing data in use session id not working

Tags: php

Data which is available in the database is not showing in the table. How do I solve this?

The code:

```
<?php
$getPro=$ct->getCartProduct();
if($getPro){
    $i=0;
    while($result = $getPro->fetch_assoc()){
         $i++;
         ?>
         <?php echo $result['productName'];?>
<?php } }?>
```

This is the function:

```
 public function getCartProduct(){
      $sid=session_id();
      $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE sid='$sid'";
      $result =$this->db->select($query);
      return $result;
 }
```

Comment: Did you [start the session](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Comment: Unrelated, but, why do you break our of PHP then back in to do actual PHP code? `?>  <?php echo`

Comment: please echo $getPro what it shows ????

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($getPro);`?

Answer (score -1):

Use this: 
`$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE sid=".$sid;` in your code. 
NOT this:
`$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE sid='$sid'";`
Hope it helps you. Keep coding.

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_cart WHERE sid=".$sid; use this result is: Unknown column '2pras1jf3cl440p1cspqjbh5u6' in 'where clause'30

Comment: Did you have any column named like that ?

Comment: no any column this name "2pras1jf3cl440p1cspqjbh5u6"

Comment: This problem seems weird to me. Sorry for not being able to help. And I also do not know much of OOP in PHP.